# doctrine2 Detach doesn't work when there is association to put order in session

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm trying to detach an object from entity_manager in doctrine2 in order to put him in session but it doesn't work. not when there is Association.

Ex:

```
<?php
namespace Travelyo\CoreBundle\Entity\Order;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**

 *     @ORM\Table(name="bundles")
 *    /
class Bundle 
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order", inversedBy="orders",cascade={"detach","merge","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $order;
 }
```

There is no other relation in order.

But when I'm trying to do that

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$bundle = $em->getRepository('TravelyoCoreBundle:Order\Bundle')->find(27);
$em->detach($bundle);
$em->detach($bundle->order);
serialize($bundle);
```

It's not working, I have all the object dependecies, proxies,...

If I'm doing that before detach
     $bundle->setOrder(new Order());

Then the serialize is perfect, I just have the bundle.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your object is detached, it still has references to the doctrine components used to create it.

As a simple advice, I can tell you to simply serialize the object identifier instead. That's much cleaner, and while it will require you to perform a query on the other side (the unserialize part), you will avoid a lot of problems.

Just don't serialize your entities, it's just messy.